# Adding two weeks php

Tags: php, sql, date

I'm trying to add two weeks to sql result that comes back as 16/11/2016. When I do something like

```
$twoweeks = strtotime($time_db);

$expiry_date = $twoweeks;
$date = strtotime($expiry_date);
$date = strtotime("+14 day", $date);
echo date('d/m/y', $date);
```

I keeping getting 15/01/70... any ideas?

Comment: The reason you get 15/01/1970, is because you are adding two weeks to the beginning of time, or rather the UNIX epoch.  Somewhere your timestamp is assigned as 0.

Comment: now u have lot of answers, try them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake on line 4 by putting a number variable as a first parameter of `strtotime`. `strtotime` expects a string of a valid date/time format as a first parameter otherwise it returns FALSE.

How I think your code should be:

```
$twoweeks = strtotime($time_db);
$date = strtotime("+ 2 weeks", $twoweeks);
echo date('d/m/y', $date);
```

Or maybe even:

```
echo date('d/m/y', strtotime($time_db . ' + 2 weeks'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$numberOfWeeks = 2;

$newTime = strtotime($time_db) + ($numberOfWeeks * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
```

or you can do directly in (mysql) select

```
select date_add( your_column, INTERVAL 2 WEEK) from my_table;
```

Comment: You are uisng php or mysql ?   .. and $time_db is a date or a string?   .. you obtain 1/1/1970 becase you time_db is not a valid date  then adding 2 weeks you get 15/1/1970

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that your 16/11/2016 is day-month-year and the slashes are an issue.

Had your date been 11/16/2016, you would have found that it would have been OK.

You need to convert/replace those to dashes/hyphens.

```
$time_db = "16/11/2016";
$time_db = str_replace('/', '-', $time_db);

$two_weeks_later = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($time_db . "+14 days"));
// or display as Year-month-day
// $two_weeks_later = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($time_db . "+14 days"));

echo $two_weeks_later;
```

When working with dates (and times), it's best to use the built-in MySQL date/time functions, rather than storing them as plain text; it's a lot less trouble and much easier when querying.

Reference:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time());
     $date = strtotime($date);
     $date = strtotime("+14 day", $date);
    $valuedate= date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$date);
```

Try this